# Darksiders 2 transfer savegame to another computer?

Tags: darksiders-2

I played a significant portion at a friend's house, but then I didn't want to lose my save, so I copied everything out of the save file in My Documents->My Games->Darksiders 2 and Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\xxxxxxxx\50650
So fast-forward to now, when I just bought the game on sale. I tried sticking the saves in the same place, I tried creating a new save and placing the old saves in the same folder it created, but I can't get them to show up in the game.

How do I go about transferring these saves?

Answer (score 1):

Transferring savegame files this way should work if done on the same computer and steam account,In your case the steam account and PC name are probably different between the two savegames.
Usually this difference should result in "corrupted data" error rather than just not showing up.

It will take some file editing but you can still try treating this as the "corrupted data" error and try the following guides.

[Similar thread,for Darksiders 1 but should work on 2 aswell](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3003375)